# In a loop, all array elements get value of the last one

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var travel_path=[];
var point={
    "left": 0,
    "top": 0
};
while(/*some condition here*/){
    point.left+=3;
    point.top+=5;
    travel_path.push(point);
}
console.log(travel_path);
```

Now, if the `while` loop runs for 10 iterations, instead of getting the incremented values of `left` and `top` in each element, I get 10 elements with the same value of `{"left": 30, "top": 50}`.

So it seems that, even though I'm using push to append elements to the end of the array, it's somehow updating all the previous elements as well.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference *of a value*, you only have one single `point` object that you keep pushing, and that's the only object you're changing.

Comment: You need to create a new object in each step of the iteration and then push it to your array, right now you're pushing multiple copies of your same `point` variable.

Comment: so how do I fix it? I've tried adding var tmp=point; and then pushing tmp instead of point every time but the result is the same.

Comment: @slugo See my comment above please, I've tried declaring a new var every time but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create clone of object in each iteration of loop with `Object.assign()` and push that object to array.

```js
var travel_path = [];
var point = {
  "left": 0,
  "top": 0
};
var i = 0;

while (i++ < 5) {
  point.left += 3;
  point.top += 5;
  travel_path.push(Object.assign({}, point));
}
console.log(travel_path);
```

Comment: That did the trick. I had tried declaring a new var every time but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how `javascript` works. You can do something like this:

```
var travel_path = [];
var lastPoint;
var point = {
    "left": 0,
    "top": 0
};
while (/*some condition here*/) {
    lastPoint = travel_path[travel_path.length-1] || point;
    travel_path.push({
        left: lastPoint.left + 3,
        top: lastPoint.top + 5
    });
}
console.log(travel_path);
```

Comment: That is not a simple option because the real function doesn't actually just add +3 and +5, it performs considerably more complex calculations. So I would have to stick the entire code into a separate function and call it each time. There must be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var travel_path=[];
var point={
    "left": 0,
    "top": 0
};
while(/*some condition here*/){
    point.left+=3;
    point.top+=5;
    var tempPoint={
    "left": point.left,
    "top": point.top
    };
    travel_path.push(tempPoint);
}
console.log(travel_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you calculate the new result, you could keep a count, like `point` and push tjen a new object with the values.

```
var travel_path=[];
var point={
    left: 0,
    top: 0
};
while(/*some condition here*/){
    point.left += 3;
    point.top += 5;
    travel_path.push({ left: point.left, top: point.top });
}
console.log(travel_path);
```